# Aligning fontawesome icons correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, styling

I'm currently can't find a way to correctly align the text after the icons on my mobile menu, because icon sized differ text isn't aligned properly.

[Mobile Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM7EF.png)

Does anyone know something that'll do the trick? Menu is generated using Wordpress.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Use the class `fa-fw` for your icons. That will render all icons with the same width.

[See the official documentation](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#fixed-width):

> Use `fa-fw` to set icons at a fixed width. Great to use when different icon widths throw off alignment. Especially useful in things like nav lists & list groups.

Comment: This did the trick for me , thanks!

Comment: If it helped you, please feel free to accept the answer. I'd also like an upvote ;)

Comment: Finally a correct answer! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `fontAwesome` instead i have used `Google Icons`. Assuming they work the same way you can align elements like this

```
.icons{
    width:30px
    height:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
}    

<div class='menu'><i class='icons'>Home</i></div>
```

You can learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp) How to play with Font Awesome icons

You can view [Official documentation here](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/)